# model = CSRNet() | TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: machine-learning, heatmap

```
transform=transforms.Compose([
                      transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                    std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

root = '/home/meet/CSRNet-pytorch/ShanghaiTech/'
part_A_train = os.path.join(root,'part_A/train_data','images')
part_A_test = os.path.join(root,'part_A/test_data','images')
part_B_train = os.path.join(root,'part_B/train_data','images')
part_B_test = os.path.join(root,'part_B/test_data','images')
path_sets = [part_A_test]

#defining the image path
img_paths = []
for path in path_sets:
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
       img_paths.append(img_path)

model = CSRNet()
model = model.cuda()
```

On running model = CSRNet() I get an "Typeerror: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type"

I am referring to a tutorial to get the number of people count from crowd images.

This is the tutorial I am referring to:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/02/building-crowd-counting-model-python/

This is the kernal output window : -

model = CSRNet()
Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/vgg16-397923af.pth" to /home/meet/.torch/models/vgg16-397923af.pth
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    model = CSRNet()

File "/home/meet/CSRNet-pytorch/model.py", line 16, in **init**
    mod = models.vgg16(pretrained = True)

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/vgg.py", line 152, in vgg16
    model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['vgg16']))

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/model_zoo.py", line 66, in load_url
    _download_url_to_file(url, cached_file, hash_prefix, progress=progress)

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/model_zoo.py", line 73, in _download_url_to_file
    u = urlopen(url, stream=True)

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in request
    with sessions.Session() as session:

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 346, in **init**
    self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter())

File "/home/meet/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 117, in **init**
    super(HTTPAdapter, self).**init**()

Comment: Please give a link to github to see all your code together

Comment: I solved it! Restarted the kernel.